# PHP - Is it possible for an if statement to execute without the conditions been met?

Tags: php

```
$example = 0;    

if ($password == "123") {
    $example = 1;
    }else{
    die("Incorrect Password");
    }    

    if ($example === 1) {
        echo "Conditions Met.";
        }else{
        echo "Conditions Not Met";
        die();
        }

    //Super important code that should not run if $example does not equal 1
```

Is it possible for code like this to execute if the condition has not been met, I am including guessing the password, or some kind of brute force method.

I am just asking if an if statement can somehow break, is there any way for an if statement to mess up and somehow let the user execute the theoretical code below without knowing the password.

**Just to clarify, I am not talking about guessing the password, or any over vulnerability like that, I am purely talking about whether it's possible for an if statement to execute if the statement conditions are not met, for example if the server was under extreme load, could it make a mistake as such?**

Comment: No.  The functionality of an `if` statement is fairly well established.  The question is... Why do you *think* the `if` keyword in PHP might be broken?

Comment: no it shouldn't, else it would be a bug (direct Memory acces from a program on the same Server not included)

Comment: No it isn't, but I wouldn't use `die()` to achieve that.

Comment: The `if` statement ist not likely to "break". However, conditions themself can be attacked. There are scenarios like buffer overflow or early null-termination in strings or encoding attacks which are misinterpreted in some conditions.

Comment: And as mentioned by others, `die` should not be used since in certain circumstances security relevant information could be exposed.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone So how should it be killed without using die()?

Comment: `die`/`exit` are useful to return an exit code to the CLI. A web application should always generate a full response and end up normally. In the easiest case you could set a `bool` value indicating if a user successfully logged in and produce the outputs depending on that flag - e.g. an html page telling that the login attempt failded.

Answer (score 4):

No, the `if` part of it will not run, provided you include the `else` part the flow is automatically transferred to `else` if the `if` condition is not met.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your main question no the likelihood of an if being broken is slim to none. That would make 100% of the code in production right now unreliable. How many sites do you visit that have a username and password and they do the same thing (kind of).

You really need to revisit this code should be consistent, formatted and limited in flows

You have 2 die versions (which is not the best option)
The code formatting is all over the place and you have logic checks that really just make the flow harder to follow for no advantage.

```
$example = 0;    
//For the sake of simplicity I will assume you know this is not how to handle passwords in real life.

//If not please comment and I will give a better example. 

if ($password == "123") {
    $example = 1;
}else{
    //Die version 1
    die("Incorrect Password"); //If you are here then nothing below in this script will run.
}    

//Literally just a continuation of the code you have uptop?
if ($example === 1) {
    echo "Conditions Met.";
}else{
    //Die version 2
    echo "Conditions Not Met";
    die();
}

//This is the code that should be in the if.
//Super important code that should not run if $example does not equal 1
```

Refactoring this can be as simple as:

```
//For the sake of simplicity I will assume you know this is not how to handle passwords in real life.

//If not please comment and I will give a better example. 

if ($password == "123") {
    //Super important code that should not run if bad password!
}else{
    //Killing a script is bad form
    //Redirect them to a login page or something.
}
```